# Weka: Matching Attribut Names

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have two weka `Instances` classes. I am trying to identify attributes in one that have the same name as attributes in the other. However, using:

```
if (testing.attribute(i).name() == training.attribute(j).name())
```

raises `False` for every attribute. Here are the arff files for each. As you can see, both contain `attr1`,`attr2`, and `attr3`.

```
@relation SampleTrain3Attributes
@attribute attr1 numeric
@attribute attr2 {a,b,c}
@attribute attr3 numeric
@data
1,a,2
3,b,4
5,c,6
7,a,8
```

---

```
@relation SampleTest5Attributes
@attribute attr1 numeric
@attribute attr2 {a,b,c}
@attribute attr3 numeric
@attribute attr4 {d,e,f}
@attribute attr5 numeric
@data
1,a,2,d,3
3,b,4,f,4
5,c,6,e,8
7,a,8,d,9
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the strings themselves, not the references to them --

```
if (testing.attribute(i).name().equals(training.attribute(j).name()))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Attribute.name()` returns a `String`. When comparing `String`s using `==`, you're comparing references. In general this yields only true if the references are identical, i.e., point to the exact same object. If you want to check whether they have identical contents, use `String.equals()`, i.e.,

```
if (testing.attribute(i).name().equals(training.attribute(j).name()))
```